# Count backwards how many days from today to find stock price

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm running the following code to get Options price (puts) and filter strikes based on a customised defined range premium (**premium_range**) so I get the strikes currently offering the premium desired.

Also I get the stock prices of the same tickers by using the getSymbols command.

The code runs properly

```
    library(quantmod)
    Symbols<-c  ("AA","AAPL","FB","NVDA")
    Options.20220414 <- lapply(Symbols, getOptionChain)
    names(Options.20220414) <- Symbols


    premium_range <- c(0.8, 1.2)

    Puts_premium_filtered<-lapply(Options.20220414, function(x) subset(x$puts, x$puts$Ask >= premium_range[1] & x$puts$Ask <= premium_range[2] ))

    getSymbols(Symbols,from="2020-03-01", src="yahoo" )

    stock_data = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)

    stock_prices <- do.call(list, mget(names(stock_data)[stock_data]))
```

Now, I’d like to count backwards from today in stock price of last 2 years approximately to know how many days ago the stock price was equal or less than the strike price of the Puts premium filtered.

For that reason I get the stocks prices with **getSymbols** and would like to use the **Strike** value of **Puts_premium_filtered** and count backwards in **stock_prices** to know how many days ago the stock **closed equal or less** than the Strike value column in **Puts_premium_filtered**

The desired result would be a new column called "Days_to_strike" in **Puts_premium_filtered** ,which should calculate how many days ago the price of the stock closed equal or less than the strike value in Puts_premium_filtered.

Comment: The Strike value isn't unique. Which one would you use? (Take a look at `Puts_premium_filtered[["AA"]][["Strike"]]`)

Comment: Good point and thanks for letting me know my approach was wrong. Honestly, I'd need to use all of them, but that would be not possible to include in a single column. Maybe it's a good idea to create a new data set?